# What are the Server Sent Request (SSE) Good practices with database?

Tags: php, database, performance, server-sent-events

I just discovered Server Sent Request and I find it very useful. I have tested with php server side.

In the php case with the while(1) to keep the connection opened, I ask me, and now, I ask the question of performance if I use database connection.

For example, if I want to create a notification system based on server sent event for a user. Inside the while(1) there are a request to check if the user has notifications. If yes, I write data: ... else the looping continue to while(1). And again and again to check in the database...

I think the risk is to have: "too many connections" on the database.

What are the good practices in this case ?

Thank you to advice me